# How to debug svelte-loader-hot giving me a "cannot find module 'svelte/package.json'" error?

Tags: javascript, webpack, meteor, svelte

I'm trying to get svelte hot module replacement working with Meteor but the svelte-loader-hot package is giving me this error:

`ERROR in ./imports/App.svelte Module build failed (from ./node_modules/svelte-loader-hot/index.js): Error: Cannot find module 'svelte/package.json'`

The regular svelte-loader works fine. I'm assuming this has to do with my webpack config or that I'm using Meteor.

I've installed svelte as a dependency but I guess it's having issues resolving?

```js
//webpack.config.js
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const meteorExternals = require('webpack-meteor-externals');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

import { scss, postcss } from 'svelte-preprocess'

const mode = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const dev = mode === 'development';
const hot = dev && process.env.HOT != 0

const clientConfig = {
    entry: './client/main.js',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    output: {
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    externals: [meteorExternals()],
    mode,
    plugins: [
        hot && new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.browser': true,
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(mode)
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css',
            chunkFilename: '[name].[id].css',
        }),
        new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
            assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/g,
            cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
            cssProcessorPluginOptions: {
                preset: ['default', { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }],
            },
            canPrint: true
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './client/main.html'
        })
    ].filter(Boolean),
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    query: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
                    }
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(svelte)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'svelte-loader-hot',
                    options: {
                        dev,
                        hydratable: true,
                        hotReload: hot,
                        hotOptions: {
                            optimistic: true,
                        },
                        preprocess: [
                            scss({
                                includePaths: [
                                    './imports/theme',
                                    './node_modules',
                                    './imports/components'
                                ]
                            }),
                            postcss()
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader',
                    'postcss-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                includePaths: [
                                    './imports/theme',
                                    './node_modules',
                                    './imports/components'
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

const serverConfig = {
    target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc.
    entry: './server/main.js',
    externals: [meteorExternals()],
    devServer: {
        hot: hot
    }
}

module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig];
```

Comment: webpack? I don't think you want to use webpack with meteor, neither do I think you need it. How did you install svelte? `meteor npm install svelte`?

Comment: BTW, please try to avoid posting large sections of code. It's always best to try and just post the minimal code fragment needed to reproduce the issue, which is good debugging practice anyways.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I'll take note about the large code blocks in the future, I figured it might be helpful to see the whole thing. Yes, I used `meteor npm install svelte`.

I need to use webpack to process SCSS in the svelte-material-ui components. There is a webpack package for meteor, `ardatan:webpack`.

Comment: Oh interesting, I had no idea that existed. Thanks for sharing.